# Recursive Descent Parser using Python and PLY

Tags: python, parsing, recursive-descent

I apologize for my very basic question but, I'm really struggling here.  I need to make a recursive descent parser.  I'm working in Python and using PLY.  My grammar follows:

< list > → (< sequence >) | ()

< sequence > → < listelement > , < sequence > | < listelement >

< listelement > → < list > | NUMBER

Would that look something like this?  Am I way off?  The end goal is to read a list into a data structure and then print it out.

```
def p_list(p)
    'list : "("sequence")" | "("")"'

def p_sequence(p)
    'sequence : list_el","sequence | list_el'

def p_list_el(p)
    'list_el : list | NUMBER'
```

If anyone was wondering what the full solution was I'll post it shortly.

Comment: Does NUMBER require defining, or is it a special definition in PYR?

Comment: What's PYR? Do you mean PLY?

Comment: I can't find this supposed PYR with Google. A link to where you got it would be helpful. Although based on what I'm seeing, it really looks like you indeed mean PLY.

Comment: Sorry I do mean ply - typo

Comment: @Patashu `NUMBER` does require defining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
tokens = ("LBRACKET", "RBRACKET",
          "INTEGER", "FLOAT", "COMMA") # So we can add other tokens
t_LBRACKET = r'\('
t_RBRACKET = r'\)'
t_INTEGER = r'\d+'
t_FLOAT = r'\d+\.\d+'
t_COMMA = r','

def p_list(p):
    """list : LBRACKET sequence RBRACKET
            | LBRACKET RBRACKET"""
    if len(p) == 4:
        p[0] = p[2]
    else:
        p[0] = None

def p_number(p):
    """number : INTEGER
              | FLOAT"""
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_sequence(p):
    """sequence : list_el COMMA sequence
                | list_el"""
    if len(p) == 4:
        p[0] = p[1] + p[3]
    else:
        p[0] = p[1]        

def p_list_el(p):
    """list_el : number
               | list"""
    p[0] = p[1]
```

Edit:
Quick explanation on the extra tokens: Everything in a script should eventually boil down to a token or character you've defined (So it's legal to add). By specifying them all as tokens, it's easier to read and work with.

Comment: I was just going to comment on `COMMA` being missing, but I see you've added it now.  Good job!

Comment: Yup, I missed the comma in the original post at first. Oops!

Comment: okay this is extremely helpful.  I follow almost all of it.  My only question is why are you checking on len(p) == 4?  Shouldn't it be on len(p) == 3 in both cases ((LBRACKET sequence RBRACKET) or (list_el COMMA sequence))?

Comment: Nevermind I've got it now.  In the first case list is p[0] and in the second case sequence is p[0].

Comment: Correct- the base is the token, then the rest (`p[1]`+) is everything on the right. Basically.

Comment: Okay, a few more questions: First: Doesn't list have to be the topmost definition since once we get back to list we're done?  Second: Since I want to return a list shouldn't we just be appending it be more like p[0] = p[3].append instead of adding?

Comment: Correct, p_list should be the first definition. For the sequence part -> If you append it each time, say you have `2, 3, 4` -> This could become `(2, (3, (4)))`. Think about how the two tokens, `list_el` and `sequence` should be combined.